# Translate Laravel site English and Urdu

Tags: laravel

I have custom Laravel e-commerce project in English now I want to add language translator from English to Arabic.
so can any any one tell me what will I do for that or is their any library to translate whole site by just clicking on ENG and ARB button or dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't simple. You need to look into Localization in Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization

Anyway you'll have to hire a Laravel developer (and probably also a frontend developer) to do that.